# How to do database for flutter

Tags: database, android-studio, flutter

Im trying to make an app that needs a database which can edit, update, add, delete. I have tried the codes in StackOverflow but I could not seem to find my Database table or diagram after I created it. Im new to flutter so I would appreciate if you guys could help me.

The second problem Im having is how to connect the pages to the database. Currently Im hardcoding everything and I would like to create a database which can easily be connected to all pages as there is a list of Teachers that i need to insert in the database including their name, date of birth, preferred timing/location, mobile no, gender, bank account and their profile picture.

```
Image.asset('C:/Users/tiurm/Pictures/ISGN/Logo.jpeg'),
        CircleAvatar(
            radius: 50.0,
            backgroundImage:
            AssetImage('C:/Users/tiurm/Pictures/ISGN/farreis.jpg'),

      ),
      FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          "Ustaz Farreis",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profile()),
          );
        }
),

      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50.0,
        backgroundImage:
        AssetImage('C:/Users/tiurm/Pictures/ISGN/aaron.jpg'),

      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 7),
        child: Text(
          'Ustaz Aaron',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50.0,
        backgroundImage:
        AssetImage('C:/Users/tiurm/Pictures/ISGN/ustaz.jpg'),

      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 7),
        child: Text(
          'Ustaz Daniyal',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50.0,
        backgroundImage:
        AssetImage('C:/Users/tiurm/Pictures/ISGN/mira.jpg'),

      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 7),
        child: Text(
          'Ustazah Mira',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50.0,
        backgroundImage:
        AssetImage('C:/Users/tiurm/Pictures/ISGN/amalina.jpg'),

      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 7),
        child: Text(
          'Ustazah Amalina',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50.0,
        backgroundImage:
        AssetImage('C:/Users/tiurm/Pictures/ISGN/syafiq.jpg'),

      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 7),
        child: Text(
          'Ustaz Syafiq',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      CircleAvatar(
        radius: 50.0,
        backgroundImage:`enter code here`
        AssetImage('C:/Users/tiurm/Pictures/ISGN/delisha.png'),

      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 7),
        child: Text(
          'Ustazah Delisha',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are new the most beginner-friendly backend data store would be firebase, check it out on youtube or medium, there are a lot of things you can do with it, from CRUD to authentication.